# set variable to count of rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

This isn't a complete question, but I was just wondering if there was a better or more elegant way to set a variable to the count of the number of rows from a mysql `select` statement. Currently, what I have is:

```
SET @myCount = 
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM table1
WHERE aCondition = TRUE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a `select... into` (donnow if you find this more "elegant")

```
select count(*) into @myCount
from table1
where aCondiction = TRUE;
```